# Loop over the files that match an AzureDevops pattern

Tags: azure-pipelines

My Azure pipeline has a file pattern parameter.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops

I want to make a (PowerShell, probably) step to loop through the files, but PowerShell doesn't understand the Azure pipeline file wildcards, does it?

```
$projectsToPack = '**\CompanyName.@(This|That).csproj'

echo "Projects to pack are: $projectsToPack"

foreach( $csproj in "$projectsToPack" ) {
#foreach( $csproj in Get-ChildItem "$projectsToPack" -Recurse ) { # Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
#foreach( $csproj in Get-ChildItem  -Filter "$projectsToPack" ) { # Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
  echo "csproj is $csproj"
}
```

Is it possible to loop through the files?

Answer (score 0):

Im taking the question to be

> Can Powershell understand the azure-pipelines file pattern syntax?

and the answer is no.

Powershell has its own syntax and process for globbing files (see [where-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) if its more complex than a simple glob).

e.g

```
$Projects = Get-Item **\CompanyName.*.csproj
ForEach( $Project in $Projects ) {
    # enter code here
}
```

The azure-pipelines syntax is for where you are passing a path filter expressly to a task.

Reading between the lines it looks like you want to loop over some projects and pack them.
You could use the built-in DotNetCoreCLI@2 task and pass the pattern parameter in there?

e.g

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**\CompanyName.@(This|That).csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
```

Comment: If the branch is master then I want to check that none of the projects being packed contains a reference to a pre-release package.